# Can not integrate .so library from working project to another one

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, jniwrapper

I have working project where I use `JNI` to call methods from `C` library.

My project's structure:

[image]

And code which load library:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("RemoveBackground");
}
```

It works good. But until I try to integrate this functionality in other project. I copied `jni` and `libs` folders. Also all `three classes` without `RemoveBackgroundActivity` (test activity). And when I compiled this project I have an exeption:

```
1663-1663/com.example.Activities E/dalvikvm﹕ The lib may be ARM... trying to load it [/data/data/com.example.Activities/lib/libRemoveBackground.so] using houdini
1663-1663/com.example.Activities E/dalvikvm﹕ dvmHoudiniDlopen returns 0x9833cf40 with bool=1
```

Do you know how to solve the problem or some other way to do this?

Comment: 1) I'm not sure about IDEA, but in Eclipse you have to enable native development in the project. You can't just copy the directory. 2) I doubt you needed the libs directory unless you are linking other libraries. Part of me thinks it's trying to load the library built in the other project. 3) what's in Application.mk? It's usually not necessary. 4) Unless you are registering native methods explicitly, the JNI calls will probably need updating because of the package name (that may be a future issue, though).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the `RemoveBackground.so` native library you try to use wasn't built for ARM architecture. I'm not sure about Linux, but on Mac OS X you can check the supported architectures of a native library using [lipo](http://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/lipo/) command. For example:

```
lipo -info /usr/lib/RemoveBackground.so
```